# How to make Netbeans debugger not to pause each new php file execute?

Tags: php, apache, netbeans, xdebug, breakpoints

I am debugging PHP site running on remote Apache2 server with xdebug and NetBeans.

I found that tracing pauses each new PHP file loads.

How to control this feature? I wish to turn it off and on by will.

Comment: This is being asked over and over again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434172/debug-php-with-xdebug-over-amfphp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools->Options->PHP

uncheck 'Stop at first line'