# Debug php with xdebug over AMFPHP

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, amfphp

I'm using WAMP Server 2.2, which practically comes with xdebug already on. I managed to start a debug fine using NetBeans 7.1.
My problem is that its not actually the breakpoints that I mark on the application that starts the debug. It is always the index.php from AMFPHP.
Am I doing something wrong? Does anyone uses xdebug and AMFPHP? Any tips?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netbeans and other IDEs will always break on the first line of the script. There is an option to turn at off:

Go to Tool-> Options-> PHP-> General and uncheck Stop at first line.